# Stack() Widget not centering all sub widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `Text()` widget I am trying to stack on a `CircularProgressIndicator()`

I thought it would be as simple as just wrapping them both in a `Stack()` widget but the text is not centered.

I tried wrapping the `Text()` in a `Center()` widget but that did not solve the issue:

```
                    return Expanded(
                      child: PageView(
                        controller: pageViewController,
                        children: [
                          PackSummaryWeightGraph(
                              categoryWeightList: categoryWeightList,
                              totalWeight: totalWeight),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Text((packedItemsPercent * 100)
                                        .toString()),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 150,
                                      width: 150,
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        value: packedItemsPercent,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Center(
                            child: Text('Third Page'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
```

**Bonus points** if there is a way to have the `CircularProgressIndicator()` fill the space without hard coding its width and height...

[image]

Comment: Stack has an alignment argument `Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [...])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) has an alignment argument:

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center, 
  children: [...],
),
```

If you want to fill the given space use the [`SizedBox.expand` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html):

```dart
SizedBox.expand(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
    value: packedItemsPercent,
  ),
),
```

One issue with the above is that if the available space has a different height than width you will end up with an oval shaped indicator rather than a circle. You can avoid this by wrapping it in an [AspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget:

```dart
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: SizedBox.expand(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: packedItemsPercent,
    ),
  ),
),
```

See complete demo:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  double packedItemsPercent = .67;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Text((packedItemsPercent * 100).toString()),
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: SizedBox.expand(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: packedItemsPercent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Make sure that any widget like `Expanded` or `SizedBox.expand` is not inside of an infinite sized container like a `ListView` or similar. Expanded means to take up the maximum available space, but that isn't possible if you have an infinite amount of space.

Comment: alignment: Alignment.center,  worked perfectly! 

The SizedBox.expand did not. NOw I dont see the circular progress indicator at all.

Comment: @TenDigitGrid I added a complete demo above.

Comment: I am in an Expanded, Pageview, column, center, sizedbox. Are any of those infinite ammounts of space?

Comment: I got this error when trying to sized.box and aspect ratio:

https://pastebin.com/eZA2M8F8

Comment: @TenDigitGrid The error suggests that you don't have a bound on the height. My guess is due to the column. I would probably remove the column altogether, I'm not sure what the point of a column with one element is. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI

Comment: Removing the column makes everything expand. But I had the column to center everything. Now everything is at the top 

https://ibb.co/wCKJP3s

Comment: sooo just learned how to use the dev tools widget inspector :-)

Solved my issue I had another column that the text was in and needed to center that with cross axis and main axis :-)

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the alignment of the Stack to center:

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    // ...
  ],
);
```

To get the circular progress indicator to fill the space, you should be able to use a `FittedBox` with a `Positioned.fill` widget:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: packedItemsPercent
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: fitted box and positioned filled actually made it smaller...